# How do I fully hide my wall In Facebook?

Tags: facebook, privacy

I used to hide the wall of all it's activities and posts before, but now with the new privacy settings I can't find this option. I can only hide each post manually, but I can't hide the activities(likes and so on).

How can I do this?

Comment: For the recent activity, click the X to its right and it will allow you to hide all recent activity of that type (e.g. things you like).  (If you want to unhide those later you can use Edit Options at the bottom of your Wall.)

Comment: I'm guessing you want to remove your wall.

Comment: @phwd : yes from specific people, like I used to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately by September 30th this will not be possible with the new [Timeline](https://www.facebook.com/about/timeline), the feature known as a Wall will be replaced by a timeline of your activity.